# What is the "Goal Previous Step - 1" in "Reverse Goal Path" if the goal has "Funnel" turned on?

Tags: google-analytics, goals

Say if I have a goal with "Funnel" turned on has the following settings:

```
Goal Destination:/D
Step1: /A
Step2: /B
Step3: /C
```

A session contains hits:

```
Foo → /A → /B → /C → /D
```

Will the "**Goal Previous Step - 1**" be "**Foo**" or "**C**"?

**Related question:**
If the "**Goal Previous Step - 1**" is "(entrance)" what does it means? does it mean "/A" or "/D" or "/Foo"?

I have researched and just can't find any helpful information from the official help document about this…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those unfamiliar: this question refers to the Conversions > Goals > Reverse Goal Path report, with a destination goal, so the Goal Completion Location will by definition always be `/D`.

Goal Previous Step - 1 will be the previous page hit, regardless of whether there's a funnel defined. So in your example `Foo → /A → /B → /C → /D`, the previous step 1 value will be `/C`.

`(entrance)` as the Goal Previous Step - 1 means the person landed directly on `/D`. Defining a funnel does not restrict goal conversions to people who go through the funnel, even if you've marked it as required - anyone who hits `/D` will count as a conversion.

What a funnel does accomplish is to give you more information about how people convert and where they abandon the process, via the Goal Flow and Funnel Visualization reports. The Funnel Visualization report will be limited to sessions that hit the first step of the funnel if you've marked that first step as required, but otherwise the funnel is just extra context.

Comment: wow..... I've been misunderstood that for a long time... Thank you!!! Do you mean even if I've marked the first step as "required", a session contains the page "/D" will be considered as a goal completion? For example: /Foo → /Bar → /Baz → /D. And one more question, will the order of the sequence applied strictly? For example: Step1 → random-page → Step2 → random-page → Destination ; will this also be shown in the Funnel-Visualization reports?

Comment: @yaquawa Yes, every session that hits /D will count as a goal conversion, regardless of what other pages are or are not visited. And any session that hits the first page of the funnel will show in the Funnel Visualization report (or sessions that hit *any* page of the funnel or the goal page, if the funnel step 1 isn't marked required), though I'm not sure exactly how your example would be displayed.